# Cookie to remember the last login name

Tags: php, cookies

I'm struggling to add a cookie to my existing login form.
This is what I have so far:

Login.php

```
<?php require_once('../../Connections/connBoekengidsv2.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "",        $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
 }
 return $theValue;
 }
 }

 // Hash Password field
if (isset($_POST['paswoord']) && $_POST['paswoord'] <> ""){$_POST['paswoord'] =  md5($_POST['paswoord']);}
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();


$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
$_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
$loginUsername=$_POST['login'];
$password=$_POST['paswoord'];
$MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
$MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "index.php";
$MM_redirectLoginFailed = "login.php?error=Foutieve+login";
$MM_redirecttoReferrer = true;
mysql_select_db($database_connBoekengidsv2, $connBoekengidsv2);


$LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT login, paswoord FROM tbl_login_boekengids WHERE login=%s AND paswoord=%s",
GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

$LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $connBoekengidsv2) or die(mysql_error());
$loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
if ($loginFoundUser) {
 $loginStrGroup = "";

if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else   {session_regenerate_id();}
//declare two session variables and assign them
$_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true) {
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
}
header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
}
else {
header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
}
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/basis.dwt.php"     codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Boekengids: login</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="../../jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../jQuery/jquery.formalize.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../jQuery/les.js"></script>
<link href="../../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
</head>

<body>
<div id="outline">
<header id="header">
<h1>Boekengids</h1>
</header>
<nav id="navigatie">
<a href="../../site_ontwerp/index.php">Overzicht boeken</a> |
<?php if ($_SESSION['MM_Username']) { ?>
<a href="../../site_ontwerp/logout.php">Logout</a>
<?php } else { ?>
<a href="../../site_ontwerp/admin/login.php">Login</a>
<?php } ?>
</nav>
<div id="data"> <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="data" -->
<h1>Admin login</h1>
<p class="error"><?php echo $_GET['error']; ?></p>
<form action="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" name="loginForm" id="loginForm" method="POST">
  <p>
    <label for="login">Login:</label>
    <input type="text" required name="login" id="login" value="<?php echo  $_COOKIE['mijnLogin'] ?>">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="paswoord">Paswoord:</label>
    <input type="password" required name="paswoord" id="paswoord">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label></label>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Login">
  </p>
</form>
```

I've read that you can not read a cookie on the same page. That it can only be done on the next page (index.php). This is where I've wrote the setcookie() code line.

index.php

```
 <?php setcookie('mijnLogin', $_POST['login'], time()+86400*30)?>
 <?php
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
 session_start();
 }
 $MM_authorizedUsers = "";
 $MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

 // *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
 function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
 // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
 $isValid = False; 

 // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
// Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
if (!empty($UserName)) { 
// Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an   ID established when they login. 
// Parse the strings into arrays. 
$arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
$arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
  $isValid = true; 
} 
// Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
  $isValid = true; 
} 
if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
  $isValid = true; 
} 
 } 
 return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "login.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers,    $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
$MM_qsChar = "?";
$MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
$MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" .urlencode($MM_referrer);
header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
exit;
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="
```

All of this code is attribute to a Server Behavior I've added. I now want to implement a cookie, so that the second time someone wants to login, the username is already filled out.
I've tried several methods of trying to add it, but none have worked.
When it test it, the cookie doesn't get created. If I change the name of the cookie to read an existing cookie, it does work. So somewhere the Login code prevents the cookie frome being created.

Answer (score 0):

this code is so messed up... but the way to solve the problem is very very easy.

Follow this procedure:
- When the user loggedIn (Alredy authenticated -> After check credentials) set the cookie with easly command setCookie(cookie_name, cookie_value, cookie_time, path); for path value I suggest you to use "/".
- Before your login page redirect, in case of user not authenticated by session value, you must check if the cookie is alredy isset (if isset -> you can proceded to "Restricted Area", instead, you must redirect to login page).

Marco